# Infowindow in Google Map is not showing at relevant point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

Infowindow is not showing at proper place in google map, all infowindow are showing at same point.

I am getting the records dynamically from the database and showing multiple markers on a single map.

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">




var markers = [
            ['<div style="float:left;"><span style="float:left; margin-right:5px;"><a href="property-detail.php?ml_num=2620768"><img src="cropImage.php?image=http://links.mlslirealtor.com/mlsphotos/full/1/768/2620768.jpg&w=40&h=40" width="40" height="40" border="0" ></a></span><span style="float:left; text-align:center;">22-13 Steinway St<br>NY, 11103</span></div>', 40.772327, -73.906257],['<div style="float:left;"><span style="float:left; margin-right:5px;"><a href="property-detail.php?ml_num=2618343"><img src="cropImage.php?image=http://links.mlslirealtor.com/mlsphotos/full/1/343/2618343.jpg&w=40&h=40" width="40" height="40" border="0" ></a></span><span style="float:left; text-align:center;">44-09 Broadway<br>NY, 11103</span></div>', 40.7584945, -73.9185441],['<div style="float:left;"><span style="float:left; margin-right:5px;"><a href="property-detail.php?ml_num=2563251"><img src="cropImage.php?image=http://links.mlslirealtor.com/mlsphotos/full/1/251/2563251.jpg&w=40&h=40" width="40" height="40" border="0" ></a></span><span style="float:left; text-align:center;">48-15 31 Ave<br>NY, 11103</span></div>', 41.440565, -74.392076],['<div style="float:left;"><span style="float:left; margin-right:5px;"><a href="property-detail.php?ml_num=2474854"><img src="cropImage.php?image=http://links.mlslirealtor.com/mlsphotos/full/1/854/2474854.jpg&w=40&h=40" width="40" height="40" border="0" ></a></span><span style="float:left; text-align:center;">30-62 36th St<br>NY, 11103</span></div>', 40.7635902, -73.9188238],['<div style="float:left;"><span style="float:left; margin-right:5px;"><a href="property-detail.php?ml_num=2641580"><img src="cropImage.php?image=http://links.mlslirealtor.com/mlsphotos/full/1/580/2641580.jpg&w=40&h=40" width="40" height="40" border="0" ></a></span><span style="float:left; text-align:center;">25-92 36th St<br>NY, 11103</span></div>', 40.767123, -73.916005]         ];



var labels = ["$199k","$3.20k","$65.80k","$1.88m","$1.50m","$1.80m"];

function initializeMaps() {
    var myOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        mapTypeControl: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(pos);             


            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                 position: pos,
                 draggable: true,
                 raiseOnDrag: true,
                 map: map,
                 icon: 'assets/images/home_iconddd.png',
                 labelContent: labels[i],
             //labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                labelClass: "labels" // the CSS class for the label
                //labelStyle: {opacity: 0.95}
            });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
               infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
    </script>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:850px"></div>
```

Comment: please reformat your code, it's nearly unreadable

Comment: @fablife i have formatted it but still showing same issue...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map API - multiple icons in wrong spot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202569/google-map-api-multiple-icons-in-wrong-spot)

Comment: @fablife still getting same issue, i don;t know why... but getting trouble for me. if i am not using label with marker type, its wokring fine, but if i use, its star showing that issue.

Comment: @geocodezip markers are at same position buddy, but infowinodow is just showing at one point for all the markers.

Comment: Did you look at that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202569/google-map-api-multiple-icons-in-wrong-spot) or the answer to it?  There is an issue with the version of MarkerWithLabel you are using and the current version of the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Comment: geocodezip is right. If you use plain markers instead of `MarkerWithLabel` your code is working.

Comment: @geocodezip, Thank you for the help, i included the latest js file for "Markwithlabel" and issue has been resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your addListener, it has a function(marker, i)... callback but you are also using i as a loop variable

I can't test (you didn't provide the full code), so maybe this is garbage:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
               infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
```