# MarkerWithLabel shows the info window in only one marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

When i click on a marker it shows an info window but not in the right marker.
It does show the correct window but in the wrong marker.

I'm only having this problem when i am using MarkerWithLabel. a normal marker works fine.

**Get json**

```
 // Load markers
function loadMarkers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetJsonMarkers'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            handleMarkerAndWindow(value);
        });
    });
}
```

**Create marker and add an listener (includes all functionality for markers and windows)**

```
    function handleMarkerAndWindow(jsonMarker) {

    // Create and get marker
    var marker = createMarker(jsonMarker.Latitude, jsonMarker.Longitude, jsonMarker.Content);

    // Add marker to map
    marker.setMap(googleMap);

    // Create info window
    var infoMarkerWindow = createAndReturnMarkerWindow(jsonMarker.Content);

    // Add to array
    addMarkerAndWindow(marker, infoMarkerWindow);

    // Add listener to show the info window on marker click
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

        // Close all windows
        closeAllMarkerWindows();

        // Open window
        infoMarkerWindow.open(googleMap, marker);
    });
}
```

**Create marker**

```
  // Creates a new marker
function createMarker(latitude, longitude, title) {
    return new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: createPosition(latitude, longitude),
        title: title,
        draggable: false,
        raiseOnDrag: false,
        labelContent: "$425K",
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
        labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
        labelStyle: { opacity: 0.75 },
        labelInBackground: false,
        map : googleMap
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just read: [Google Map API - multiple icons in wrong spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202569/google-map-api-multiple-icons-in-wrong-spot)

Apparantly there is an issue with the library script i was using.

Now i am using the packed version in the given link and it works fine again.