# jquery.ui.maps with multiple markers and labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using jquery.ui.maps and I'm populating the markers from json. Using the code below I see the labels where the markers should be but I only see one marker on the page. If I comment out `'marker': MarkerWithLabel` then I see all of the markers but no labels. What do I need to do to see the label and the markers?

```
$.each( result, function(i,marker) {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
        'id': i,
        'bounds': true,
        'marker': MarkerWithLabel,
        'labelContent': '<a class="hint--top hint--always" data-hint="'+this.price+'">'+this.price+'</a>',
        'labelAnchor': new google.maps.Point(6, 10),
        'labelClass': "labels",
        'labelStyle': {opacity: 0.75},
        'labelInBackground': false,
        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude)
    }).click(function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': marker.street_address_full }, this);
    });
});
```

Comment: please use www.jsfiddle.net to show us what you have already.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle but I'm not familiar with it and I can't get the json data to work which originally came from php. http://jsfiddle.net/2qcbb3rj/9/

Comment: Sounds like the [issue with MarkerWithLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202569/google-map-api-multiple-icons-in-wrong-spot/22204169#22204169) is your map using that? Looks like it might be ('marker': MarkerWithLabel)

Comment: Your fiddle has issues with your JSON.  If I use version the latest version of markerwithlabel, and add error handling for the issues with the JSON, [it works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/2qcbb3rj/11/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks geocodezip! The problem was I was using an old version of MarkerWithLabel. [issue with MarkerWithLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202569/google-map-api-multiple-icons-in-wrong-spot/22204169#22204169)