# Only one "MarkerWithLabel" marker displays on Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using MarkerWithLabel.js to show multiple markers on a google map with labels attached to each marker. 
The labels are correctly displayed, however I only have one marker showing. 
What exactly am I missing. I have been searching for a solution for days but none worked.
Below is the javascript code I am using.
Please help !!!

```
var markers = <?php print(json_encode(str_replace('/','',$markers)))?>;
window.onload = function() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for (i = 1; i <= markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i - 1]
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
            labelContent: i,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 30),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            labelInBackground: false
        });
        (function(marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
    }
}
```

Var markers when json_encoded looks similar to this.

```
 var markers = [{
     "title": 'Gombak Setia',
     "lat": '3.218937',
     "lng": '101.7167931',
     "description": 'Gombak Setia, Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, 53100'
 }, {
     "title": 'Jalan Desa Melawati',
     "lat": '3.2331742',
     "lng": '101.7061447',
     "description": 'Jalan Desa Melawati, Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, 53100'
 }, {
     "title": 'Jalan Intan (Gombak)',
     "lat": '3.22317',
     "lng": '101.71588',
     "description": 'Jalan Intan (Gombak), Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, 53100'
 }, {
     "title": 'Jalan Madrasah',
     "lat": '3.218515',
     "lng": '101.717801',
     "description": 'Jalan Madrasah, Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, 53100'
 }];
```

Comment: Can you post some sample entries for markers? We need to see what does `var markers` look like.

Comment: @SalmanA I edited the post and added the json of the markers. and I said, the labels are displayed properly, but not the markers(the pins)

Comment: They are not the same, and even when I zoom in, still only one marker is displayed. yet, the labels are displayed separately from each other, and at the right lat + lng

Comment: My bad. It is working with the latest version of MarkerWithLabel library.

Comment: @SalmanA exactly :) I loaded the latest version and now it is working;

Comment: Solution here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202569/google-map-api-multiple-icons-in-wrong-spot/22204169#22204169